# extract a pattern with dot substring from a string in R

Tags: regex, r, date, pattern-matching, substring

I have a set of characters like

```
data <- c("ABS Spring Meeting 5.14.15", "DEFG Sellors Tour 10.28.14", "DDCC Fun at the Museum 4.4.15", "GAME CS vs. Washington 11.01.14", "BSS Studio 54 5.13.15","Pas-12 3.5.15")
```

As you can notice, the last set of digit is date of event. I want to convert them into date

```
date <- c("2015-05-14","2014-10-28","2015-04-04","2014-11-01","2015-05-13","2015-03-05")
```

Feel like I have to substring this kind ("5.14.15", "10.28.14", "4.4.15", "11.01.14", "5.13.15", "3.5.15") of pattern, then do the date convert.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: other characters like "BSS Studio 54 5.13.15","Pas-12 3.5.15"

Answer (score 5):

In base R, and provided the date is always at the end of the string, you can use

```
as.Date(sub(".*\\s", "", data), "%m.%d.%y")
# [1] "2015-05-14" "2014-10-28" "2015-04-04" "2014-11-01"
```

Here, the regular expression is simply

- `.*` everything
- `\\s` a space character

So this removes everything up to and including the final space character.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is with `lubridate`. If you supply the general format, it will try to figure it out for you:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(data)
[1] "2015-05-14 UTC" "2014-10-28 UTC" "2015-04-04 UTC" "2014-11-01 UTC"
```

If your data becomes more complicated with other numbers you can use a string extraction method. Like so:

```
mdy(sub(".*?([0-9.]+)$","\\1", data))
```

In the pattern `".*?([0-9.]+)$"`:

- `.*?` matches all characters and spaces. The question mark allows the next part of pattern be matched fully.
- `([0-9.]+)$` searches for the longest stretch of digits and decimal points reaching the end of the string marked by the dollar sign. The parantheses create a group of the tokens inside of it. We will use that group for the next step.
- `"\\1"` returns the capture group from the pattern and discards the rest of the match.

There are many websites that will go much further into regular expressions than I can. Since it is used in nearly every programming language, it will be well worth your time to invest at least a few hours in its study.

I learned a lot with this free Perl book online. Check out Ch. 5 here:

https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/

This site has a sub-section focusing on R

http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: it's cool and a little alarming that `mdy()` just ignores all the extraneous verbiage ...

Comment: lubridate only work partially for my database. My whole table contains about 300 names, there are some other numbers contained in the name, e.g. "BSS Studio 54 5.13.15", then it is not work for this.

Comment: added the extract method.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is perfect. but one more small question, what does "\\1" means?

Comment: It substitutes the entire match for the part in the parantheses. I will add more to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, will spend the time on this for sure

Comment: You have not accepted any of the answers in your questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- data <- c("ABS Spring Meeting 5.14.15", 
   "DEFG Sellors Tour 10.28.14", "DDCC Fun at the Museum 4.4.15", 
    "GAME CS vs. Washington 11.01.14", "BSS Studio 54 5.13.15",
    "Pas-12 3.5.15")
library("lubridate")
library("stringr")

mdy(str_extract(data,"[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){2}$"))
## [1] "2015-05-14 UTC" "2014-10-28 UTC" "2015-04-04 UTC" "2014-11-01 UTC"
## [5] "2015-05-13 UTC" "2015-03-05 UTC"
```

The regular expression `"[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){2}$"` means "more than one numeral (`[0-9]+`), followed by two (`{2}`) instances of (one dot (`\\.`) followed by more than one numeral `[0-9]+`), followed by the end of the string (`$`)"

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){2}$" a little bit, I am learning.